# Set diagonal of second and third array dimensions to 0

Tags: r

I would like to be able to set the diagonals of the second and third dimension in a matrix to zero, as shown below:

```
array<-array(1,dim=c(3,3,3))
array[,1,1]<-0
array[,2,2]<-0
array[,3,3]<-0
```

I could always use a loop, but this part of my script needs to be fast.  Is there a function that can do this all at once?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, this is also a loop:

```
sapply(1:3,function(i) a[,i,i] <<- 0)
```

but I think it will be fast enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: Probably the use of `<<-` but who knows with people sometimes. +1

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution (might be faster if you less rows than `i`s):

```
apply(a, 1, function(x) diag(x) <- 0)
```